# How to extract screen size from title using Google Dialogflow

Tags: machine-learning, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, entities

I have different laptops having title as below.

1. Acer One 10 S1002-15XR NT.G53SI.001 **10.1 Inch** Laptop (Quad Core/2GB/32GB eMMC/Win 10/Touch) Dark Silver
2. Acer One S1003 Nt Lcqsi 001 Hybrid (2 In 1) Intel Atom 2 Gb 25.65cm(**10.1**) Windows 10 Home - Black
3. Acer One S1003 Nt Lcqsi 001 Hybrid (2 In 1) Intel Atom 2 Gb 25.65cm(**10.1"**) Windows 10 Home - Black
4. Acer One S1003 Nt Lcqsi 001 Hybrid (2 In 1) Intel Atom 2 Gb 25.65cm(**10.1Inch**) Windows 10 Home - Black
5. HP Spectre 13 i7 8GB 512GB SSD **10.1 Full HD** (1920x1080) Touch Back-lit KeyBoard Intel HD 620 No CD/DVD Drive Dark Ash

So all the above laptops has 10.1 inch screen size, but it is typed differently. So how can I generalize all these to common one as **10_inch** using google's Dialogflow.

I have made screen_size entity like below.
[image]

But I don't want all possible screen sizes to be specified in entity.

Can we do this using system entity or composite entity?

Comment: How are you expecting to have users say these things? (Or type, I guess.) What will the conversation with the Assistant look like? There are several possible solutions, but they really depend on the characteristics of the conversation.

Comment: You might be able to train a number followed by " or by inch. I said "ten point one" and that was turned into the correct decimal.

Comment: @Prisoner we are using dialog flow GET API to extract things from product title and to make filters like screen_size,RAM, storage and all.What will be the optimal solution for this?

Comment: Can we make using system entities like " @ sys.number:number inch" or " @ sys.number:number Full HD " . Is there any other options?

Comment: Parsing this sort of product information is outside of the normal use case for Dialogflow, which is generally intended for use in building conversational experiences (such as chatbots).

Comment: @DanImrie-Situnayake Is there tool which is apt for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Parsing this sort of product information is outside of the normal use case for Dialogflow, which is generally intended for use in building conversational experiences that involve natural language (such as chatbots).

If you're looking for an API, I had some success in extracting the information you are looking for using the [Cloud Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/).

There's a tool you can use to test it out; enter the string, hit "Analyze" and then click "Syntax". For all the examples you gave above, the screen size was extracted as a `num` part of speech.

Even so, these APIs were designed for use with natural language. The machine learning model it is based on was not trained on this sort of input text, so it can't extract meaning from it.

As an alternative, you could try training your own extractor using a machine learning toolkit such as [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), or just write some crazy regex or string parsing algorithm.

Comment: What about NLTK or OpenNLP ? which is better ? can they serve this purpose?